# Rendering photo realistic views of 3D printable objects

Tags: rendering

I would like to make realistic pictures of my 3D printable objects blended into certain backgrounds.
For example, 3D printable objects created in Blender and merged into a photo taken of my shelf.

What blender processes must I learn? Some suggestions would be appreciated so I can google them.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi :). For this you'll need a basic shadowcatcher setup + FSpy to match the camera angle :). Lots of tutorials on YT to do exactly that.

Comment: Thanks for this tip!